# Convert nested list into dataframe python

Tags: python

Hello i have the below nested list, i would like to find out how to convert to dataframe with the columns headings as

Columns  | category | datetime | headline  | id  | image | related  | source  |summary | URL

Row 1
Row 2
Row 3

Thanks!!!

```
[{'category': 'company news',
  'datetime': 1592907180,
  'headline': 'Michigan-assembled Ford Ranger named ‘most American-made car’ in '
              'annual list that includes Tesla for first time',
  'id': 13507115,
  'image': '',
  'related': 'TSLA',
  'source': 'Yahoo',
  'summary': 'The Michigan-built Ford Ranger pickup truck, resurrected for the '
             'U.S. market in 2019, ranks No. 1 among the most-American-made '
             'vehicles, a 15-year-old list for which high-ranking Tesla, which '
             'assembles its electric cars in Fremont, Calif., participated for '
             'the first time.',
  'url': 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/c9fc2639-267d-3222-a540-c4b76ab3cea6/michigan-assembled-ford.html'},
 {'category': 'company news',
  'datetime': 1592902816,
  'headline': 'Electric Car Charging Stations Are Finally About to Take Off',
  'id': 13509709,
  'image': '',
  'related': 'TSLA',
  'source': 'Yahoo',
  'summary': '(Bloomberg) -- The electric vehicle sector has been stuck for '
             'years with a chicken-and-egg problem. Until there were extensive '
             'networks of public stay ahead with the most trusted '
             'business news source.©2020 Bloomberg L.P.',
  'url': 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/electric-car-charging-stations-finally-090016800.html'},
 {'category': 'company news',
  'datetime': 1592887599,
  'headline': 'Trump Orders Freeze on Many Work Visas Through End of Year',
  'id': 13083856,
  'image': '',
  'related': 'TSLA',
  'source': 'Yahoo',
  'summary': '(Bloomberg) -- President Donald Trump signed an order Monday '
             'temporarily halting access to several employment-based visas, '
             'affecting hundred' '' '' '',
  'url': 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/trump-orders-freeze-many-visas-044639010.html'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Hello i trying to test out Finnhub API.

Comment: if i assign the below 

J = finnhub_client.company_news('TSLA', _from="2020-06-23", to="2020-06-23")
it gave me the above format.
how do i convert it to dataframe

i trying out the below documentation

https://finnhub.io/docs/api#library

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor:

```
data = your data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Result:

```
       category    datetime                                           headline        id image related source                                            summary                                                url
0  company news  1592907180  Michigan-assembled Ford Ranger named ‘most Ame...  13507115          TSLA  Yahoo  The Michigan-built Ford Ranger pickup truck, r...  https://finance.yahoo.com/m/c9fc2639-267d-3222...
1  company news  1592902816  Electric Car Charging Stations Are Finally Abo...  13509709          TSLA  Yahoo  (Bloomberg) -- The electric vehicle sector has...  https://finance.yahoo.com/news/electric-car-ch...
2  company news  1592887599  Trump Orders Freeze on Many Work Visas Through...  13083856          TSLA  Yahoo  (Bloomberg) -- President Donald Trump signed a...  https://finance.yahoo.com/news/trump-orders-fr...
```

Comment: i try to do that but it gave me this.





                                                   0
0  {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...
1  {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...
2  {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...

Comment: Fix the line `'affecting hundred',`, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine:
try it

```
# save your data to the variable data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if i assign the list manually but however the same issue persist if i run the code directly from finnhub api and try to convert to dataframe.

Below is the code, but yea have to get own api key to see it.

```
!pip install finnhub-python

import finnhub
    
# Configure API key

configuration = finnhub.Configuration(api_key={token': 'your_api_key'})
    
finnhub_client = finnhub.DefaultApi(finnhub.ApiClient(configuration))
    
J = finnhub_client.company_news('TSLA', _from="2020-06-23", to="2020-06-23")

df = pd.DataFrame(J)
df.head()

---output------

    0
0   {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...
1   {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...
2   {'category': 'company news',\n 'datetime': 159...
```

Comment: Please don't add information as a new answer but instead to your question.
In this case your code has at least one syntax error (`api_key={'token'` is the correct version). I have not used finnhub, but I assume that `J` is a list of strings. Check e.g. `print(repr(J))` to see what it looks like – maybe you need to do something such as: `J = [json.loads(line) for line in J]` before loading the `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, i spoke with Finnhub API directly and got the answer below and it works.Thanks.

```
news = finnhub_client.company_news('AAPL', _from="2020-06-01", to="2020-06-10")

df = pd.DataFrame([s.to_dict() for s in news])
print(df)
print(df.columns)
```